# Statsmodels + var_weights + cross_val_score

Tags: scikit-learn, statsmodels

Based on [that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045752/using-statsmodel-estimations-with-scikit-learn-cross-validation-is-it-possible) I created a wrapper for `statsmodels' glm` in order to use `scikit's cross_val_score`. Now I need to introduce [variance/analytic weights](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.html) via var_weights parameter of SM.GLM.

```
class Wrapper(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, family, alpha, L1_wt, var_weights):
        self.family = family
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.L1_wt = L1_wt
        self.var_weights = var_weights
    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.model = sm.GLM(endog = y, exog = X, family=self.family, var_weights = self.var_weights)
        self.result = self.model.fit_regularized(alpha=self.alpha, L1_wt=self.L1_wt)
        return self.result
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.result.predict(X)
```

The wrapper let me successfully run:

```
sm_glm = Wrapper(family, alpha, L1_wt, var_weights)
sm_glm.fit()
```

But the cross validation

```
cross_val_score(sm_glm, x, y, cv, scoring)
```

doesn't work since cross_val_score trims (following cv folds) x and y, but not var_weights and that leads to an error:

```
ValueError: var weights not the same length as endog
```

The way I see it, I need to trek dynamically `cross_val_score` iterations and trim `var_weights` accordingly.

Any ideas how to create a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your guess is correct: `cross_val_score` is not propagating the `weights` array into the cross-validation loop and not splitting it in the same way that it splits the `X` and `y` into k-folds. I tried to replicate the error you got with some other data (inspired by the [StatsModels documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/glm_weights.html) about the difference between `var_weights` and `freq_weights`) and reading through the traceback, it appears that if the additional parameter (i.e. `var_weights`) is not passed through the `fit()` method implemented by your custom estimator, it is not picked up to be used in cross-validation.

I went around it in the following way:

```
class SMW(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, family, alpha, L1_wt):
        self.family = family
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.L1_wt = L1_wt
    def fit(self, X, y, var_weights):
        self.model = sm.GLM(endog = y, exog = X, family=self.family, var_weights=var_weights)
        self.result = self.model.fit_regularized(alpha=self.alpha, L1_wt=self.L1_wt)
        return self.result
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.result.predict(X)
```

In a way, `var_weights` is actually part of the data, rather than a hyperparameter of the estimator, such as the `alpha` or `L1_wt`. So, I think it's a bit more cohesive if you would pass the array in the `fit` method, instead of the into the class constructor.

So, when you actually want to cross-validate, you can run:

```
cross_val_score(sm_glm, X, y, scoring, fit_params={'var_weights':var_weights})
```

and the `fit_params` will be passed into your custom `.fit()` method.

Comment: As simple as it should be. Thanks!